# QCompleter forces double enter

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qcompleter

I have a QCompleter that is forcing my users to hit enter twice when the popup is visible but is not used to select an item. The model for the QComboBox associated to the completed is used as the model for the completer.

```
 QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(this);
 completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
 completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
 completer->setModel(this->ui->comboBox->model());
 this->ui->comboBox->setCompleter(completer);
```

As the user enters items the list of possible completions grows. If they start to type short completions (e.g. "dir") where there are longer completions available, and they hit  without choosing anything from the popup (i.e. neither activated, highlited, or indexchanged get fired) then they are forces to hit enter again to process the text they entered. Is there a simple way around this?

thanks

Comment: I wrote a quick test program, but I wasn't able to replicate your problem.  When I hit enter once, the `activated(const QString&)` signal gets fired, even if the completer pop-up is visible.  What version of Qt are you using?  What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with Qt 4.6.2 and Visual 2008 and the situation you describe does not happen. [project available](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26267349/testCompleter.zip) if you want to try.

Compile, start, type 'something' then returb in combobox : it's registered, type 'some' and return : your combobox now has "some" and "somewhere"